# Fontsquirrel font doesn't show greek characters

Tags: css, joomla, fonts

I am currently building a local joomla website that uses both greek and english language and i want to change the font.
I visited fontsquirrel and i downloaded the font "Helsinki" (http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/helsinki) that supports greek language, but when I tried to view the results, only english characters changed.
Then, I tried downloading a webfont kit with the option "no subsetting" and again, only english characters affected.
Lastly, I tried downloading the ttf file and go to generator. I uploaded the font (Helsinki) and I chose expert.
There, I chose greek and english language and I downloaded the new webfont kit.
But when I tried to apply the changes, only english characters were affected again, and greek text disappeared.
What went wrong?

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: 'helsinkiregular';
    src: url('fonts/helsinki-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/helsinki-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/helsinki-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/helsinki-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/helsinki-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: No. Post code, because the fact that only English works **is** the problem, remember? You just told us that. Give links to the font you're using, and the site you're building, or a jsbin that replicates the problem, etc. Without those, this is just a problem between you and font squirrel, not a programming problem.

Comment: I believe it's a problem with the process I follow, so I wanted to know which is the correct way to add non-latin characters. The code is the one given in the zip file when you download the webfonkit and I only changed the path for the files. I will edit my question though and add the css code. The font is Helsinki from fontsquirrel.

Comment: You don't need all those formats, it's not three years ago anymore (thankfully). [You just need the `.woff` version](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff) (with `woff2` for [browsers that support it, maybe](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff2)), which is a header wrapper around the unaltered ttf/otf original. If the original *really* supports greek, then the WOFF version will support greek too. Where is the original font?

Comment: What do you mean original? I am not so experienced...This is the first site a am working on completely on my own. The font is http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/helsinki Although it says it supports greek language, when I try to write greek at the test drive area, the outcome remains blank. So I suppose that the font doesn't really support greek and that is the problem?

Comment: If you say "I visited fontsquirrel and i downloaded a font that supports greek language", you add that link to the post, so people can see what you really grabbed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the font through any font tool (TTX, FontForge, etc) shows that it absolutely does not support Greek. Or really anything other than Basic Latin, partially, and a handful of Latin Extended glyphs.